# Displaying mysql database with php and Jquery Datatables?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

I have been attempting to use Jquery's datatables for the first time and the tutorials available have left me rather confused.  I've done the following script trying to incorporate jquery in with my php table display that I knew was working fine. I may have something fundamentally wrong here and now I'm very stuck. Would anyone be able to clear this up? (Just trying to display a basic mysql database with jquery datatables.) Thanks very much in advance.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Sid, Fname, Lname, Email, Dtype, Mac, Date FROM StudentDeviceReg";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

    <script src="media/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        @import "media/css/demo_table.css";
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#datatables').dataTable();
        })
    </script>


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table id="datatables" class="display">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Device</th>
        <th>Mac Address</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$row["Sid"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Fname"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Lname"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Email"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Dtype"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Mac"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Date"]."</td>
          </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";


} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following section need to be either `echoed` or declared outside php brackets

```
 ?>
    <script src="media/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <style type="text/css">
            @import "media/css/demo_table.css";
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#datatables').dataTable();
            })
        </script>
    <?php
```

ALSO the section below require escape sequence or a single quote:

```
echo "<table id=\"datatables\" class=\"display\">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Device</th>
        <th>Mac Address</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>";
```

Comment: No go I'm afraid, cutting off then reinitializing the php brackets results in error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'datatables' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' on line 32

Comment: Did you echo or use the brackets?

Comment: I closed off the top php with ?> and reopened it after the scripts with <?php as in your post.  Beyond that I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Coool I added the escape sequence and it's listing now.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean error on this line?

```
echo "<table id="datatables" class="display">
```

You should note the double quotes in the attribute table, it signifies the closing echo. you can use a single quote.

```
echo "<table id='datatables' class='display'>
```

or use the backslash.

```
echo "<table id="\datatables\" class="\display\">
```